# Navigating one frame from within a second frame not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My mainpage has 2 frames. I can navigate both frames from the mainpage. I want to navigate my secondFrame from the page within my firstFrame. The code runs fine, but the frame doesn't navigate. Thanks.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<SplitView.Content>
          <Grid>
                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                 <Frame x:Name="firstFrame" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                 <Frame x:Name="secondFrame" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" />
          </Grid>
</SplitView.Content>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public void setSecondFrame()
        {
            secondFrame.Navigate(typeof(Input));
        }
```

**Calendar.xaml.cs**

```
private void selectedDate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
                MainPage mp = new MainPage();
                mp.setSecondFrame();
        }
```

It works fine if I call it from within the MainPage, but not when I call it from the Calendar page.

Thanks

Comment: have you used `F12` Developer tools to see what errors might be happening in the page..? or debugger in general..?

Comment: I am an extremely novice programmer.  Never used the F12 Developer tools.  Will look into it...  It acts as though the frame doesn't refresh the data.  For example, I'll have a page open in the frame and when I activate the click event to another page it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your call to `new MainPage()`.  This creates a whole new page rather than using your existing MainPage instance and driving that with your click handler.

You have different options to chose from, and you will have to decide what works for you.

1. Expose an instance of MainPage as a static in mainpage.cs
2. Pass MainPage (this pointer) to each frame when you navigate there
3. Variations on these ideas

For simplicity, maybe #1 is easiest.

In your class, create `public static MainPage Instance {get; private set;}`

In MainPage(), assign `Instance = this;`

From any other page where you want to use MainPage do something like:

`App.MainPage.Instance.setSecondFrame()`

You may have to tweak the above per your exact project settings/names.

Comment: @TrSpTi, did this get you unblocked?